# Why is ECMAScript import syntax designed to be Counter Intuitive to IDEs?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next, ecma, javascript-import

ECMAScript import statement is : 
`import { object } from "module";`

While I try to type it in IDEs like Visual Studio Code, it offers little intellisense( auto-complete ) because it can't predict which module I am importing from.

Wouldn't it better serve the developer if the statement was arrangement hierarchically like :

`from "module" import {object};`

I am not complaining but I am trying to understand if there is any specific performance/processing advantage to the Javascript Interpreter by having designed the statement in this order?

Comment: It was simply designed that way. I don't think there's a deep reasoning behind... Also, the reason might be the "syntax" of English: you say "*I import something from somewhere*", but you don't say "*I from somewhere import something*"; however, that's just a guess.

Comment: it's like SQL ...

Comment: The IDE is the one who should adapt to the syntax.

Comment: Sometimes it does work tho, It auto-completes if it finds an export with that name in the module in vs code and even vice versa

Comment: It does work.  If you want better auto-complete try WebStorm

Comment: Yes, I just put the `{}` in place, type the rest, cursor back and get code complete.  But yes would have been nicer not to do this.

Comment: @user120242. How does Webstorm know what imports to select before you have even typed the module name?

Comment: The needs of an IDE driving the syntax of a language would definitely be the tail wagging the dog.  But the fact that all exports must be statically declared in an ESM module (available with parsing, but not executing the code) should make the IDEs job a lot easier in general than with CommonJS modules.

Comment: @Keith https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDud4.png it indexes everything for you.  And I think Visual Studio (not Code) has some intellisense where it intelligently moves more common choices or predicts choices with some kind of algo or heuristics and puts them at the top of the list

Comment: And there's also the whole autoimports thing: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports  Although OP is more questioning the design choice of import syntax than asking for solutions I guess?

Comment: In my IDE (Webstorm) I even don't have to bother writing the import most of the times. Just type in a name in your code and the IDE finds what's available and offers to auto insert the import (in order to do this it pre-indexes all exports I suppose). It might be tricky for named exports too deep though.

Comment: @FZs Python uses "from ______ import ________" syntax. BTW come to English syntax you can always say "From somewhere I import something"

Comment: Okay, I'm not a native English speaker, and that was just a guess...